# Remove bearing cartridge on a Formula RX-142 hub

Tags: bearings, freehub

[image: Bearibg cartridge from free hub side]

I am trying to replace the free hub side bearing cartridge on this Formula RX-142 rear hub.  It came stock on my 2018 Fuji Jari 1.7 and was not available after market and I can’t get docs on it.

Do I just push forcefully from the opposite side to force the cartridge out?  I’m trying to avoid needing to buy a new hub and wheel set so I don’t want to damage the hub.

Update:  here’s a better direct view 
[image: Better view]

Comment: That slot between 10 and 11 o'clock in the photo - is it a circlip?  I'd explore that with some circlip pliers and see if it comes out.

Comment: @Criggie - Had to look up circlip. I don’t think it is.  Added a new photo above with better top view.

Comment: Can you get the freehub off?

Comment: @Andrew - I have not been able to yet.

Comment: I cant remove the lock nuts to get to the bearings? Am i right in saying you need 23mm cone spanners to remove them? Please help, I just want to remove the front wheel bearings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally you'll need a blind bearing puller to extract the bearing, most decent bike shops should have one handy.  There doesn't appear to be anything preventing removal of the bearing, so the indents are not for bearing extraction. 
If you're lucky you can get in from the back of the bearing and simply punch it out with a hammer and punch, as bearings are simply a press fit.
The tooling indents are most likely for the freehub mechanism removal.  You may have to remove the freehub if you choose to go with the hammer/punch technique; they're not always easy to undo, as most designs tighten under pedalling forces.

Comment: Something like this?  https://www.amazon.com/DASBET-Bearing-Puller-Hammer-Removal/dp/B074YMMFMG

I try to do most of my repairs if I can especially if I can get the tools reasonably priced.

Comment: @MikeJansen Yep just like that.  You'll need to double check the kit you get fits the inner diameter of the bearing.  This tool is also used often for dual suspension frame pivots if you work on mountain bikes.

Comment: The ID is 15mm which is well in range of the 4 different adapters that kit has.  I have a bolt, nut and 1" OD washers to use as a press :)  The OD of the bearing is 26mm so that should be perfect.

Comment: Following up:  Bearing puller that I referenced above worked great.

Answer (score 5):

Found a drawing of the hub.

Hope [this](https://www.sykkel.no/hjul/navboss/formula/formula-navboss-rx-142-parts-41011-fh-117k-01-p0000018000) helps.
[image: Hub]

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to get the freehub body off, you need a TB-1018 type tool, can be found on eBay.  It fits into those two notches, but it's different (and proper) size compared to the Suntour freehub tool.

That said, if you're getting any grinding it's probably bearings and not the freehub body and the blind hole bearing puller others have suggested will get those out.  You may or may not need to get the drive side bearing out in order to get the freehub off with the TB-1018 type tool.

Comment: Looking at the diagram in Michiel's answer, this doesn't sound quite right. Wouldn't that tool dismantle the freehub, exposing the pawls and bearings of the free hub itself? To me, it looks like the classic freehub threaded attachment which needs a large (12/15 mm) Allen key through the centre

Answer (score 1):

Based on the second photo, it looks like a threadded retainer ring of some sort.

Perhaps a park FR2 or similar would fit it ?

[image: Image of FR2 tool]

from https://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-2

You might also be able to use some sort of 2-pin spanner to engage the slots and rotate it.

Comment: There is threading inside the freehub body but it stops a bit before the cartridge and that ring, so I’m guessing that ring doesn’t unscrew.  Not sure what that threading is for though.  The cassette goes over the body.

Comment: The threads are for the cassette lock ring.  Don't know what I was thinking :)  I upvoted your answer because I think I need a similar tool to what you showed to get the freehub off.  Not sure that specific tool has the outer clearance I'd need but I'm guessing there's a similar tool.